# How could you retrieve a method's POD from inside a REPL or debugger?

Tags: perl

I would like to be able to see the documentation of a method/function when using it inside REPL or debuger.

Is there any module that allow you to see the documentation of a function when using REPL or  a debuger?.

Obviously if that module exist it would ask you to have your POD and code with a parseable structure in order to extract the docs. That is not a problem because I have all my code documented and I can adapt to whatever is needed. Currently I have all my methods with a preceding POD with a `=head2 method_name` and the typical lines for name, usage, example, args, return, exeptions etc

The typical example is when you are in the debuger (or REPL) and you want to use a function and you don't remember the order of arguments or their types, or the type of the return element or you want a hint for the usage.

I would like to have something like get_pod($moudle_bar, $method_foo), or even better being able to put a get_pod in a base module and being able to say `$bar->get_pod('foo')`. I know that this is not trivial and has a lot of corner cases. This is the reason that I am asking about a method-POD extractor module.

I want to show the output inside the REPL or debuger so any pointer to an anchored html-pod in a browser is not convenient for me.

It could be that there is something much more simple and I am obfuscated.

My first **brute force** and expensive approach:

```
> $self = new MyModule
> m $self # to see the available methods for double check the spelling
> # method wanted '_connect_db'
> $cmd = 'perldoc -t ' . ref($self)
> x qx{$cmd}=~/(_connect_db.*?)\n\n/msg
```

```
0  '_connect_db
     Title   : _connect_db
     Usage   :
     Function: create a database conection and return the handler
     Example : $dbh = $self->_connect_db($user, $pass, $db_name) # host is FPrefect by default
     Returns : [0] DBI $dbh object
     Args    :
                [0] $user,
                [1] $pass,
                [2] $db_name,
                [3] $host,
                [4] $db_brand # mysql, sqlite
                [5] $mode = (ro, rw) # not used now. in the future it would use this for read the user and password'
```

Obviously this works because I know that I don't have any empty lines in my method description PODs so I use `.*?)\n\n` in the regex to capture the rest of the method POD.

Do someone have any good suggestion or advice for this task?

**UPDATE:**

Following *snoopy* suggestions I have taken a look at Pod::Coverage source code and I found that Pod::Coverage::Extractor (a package inside the file for Pod::Coverage) has the method `command` that look for Pods  Item or head elements and extract them. I will take a look how to retrieve this items.

```
# package Pod::Coverage::Extractor
#extract subnames from a pod stream
sub command {
    my $self = shift;
    my ( $command, $text, $line_num ) = @_;
    if ( $command eq 'item' || $command =~ /^head(?:2|3|4)/ ) {

        # take a closer look
        my @pods = ( $text =~ /\s*([^\s\|,\/]+)/g );
        $self->{recent} = [];

        foreach my $pod (@pods) {
            print "Considering: '$pod'\n" if debug;

            # it's dressed up like a method cal
            $pod =~ /-E<\s*gt\s*>(.*)/ and $pod = $1;
            $pod =~ /->(.*)/           and $pod = $1;

            # it's used as a (bare) fully qualified name
            $pod =~ /\w+(?:::\w+)*::(\w+)/ and $pod = $1;

            # it's wrapped in a pod style B<>
            $pod =~ s/[A-Z]<//g;
            $pod =~ s/>//g;

            # has arguments, or a semicolon
            $pod =~ /(\w+)\s*[;\(]/ and $pod = $1;

            print "Adding: '$pod'\n" if debug;
            push @{ $self->{ $self->{nonwhitespace}
                    ? "recent"
                    : "identifiers" } }, $pod;
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

Another place from where to take info is [pdoc](http://pdoc.sourceforge.net/scripts.html). This script generates html for browsing APIs and I use it in [Ensembl](http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/Pdoc/ensembl/index.html) and [BioPerl](http://doc.bioperl.org/releases/bioperl-1.6.1/). I am sure I will learn something reading the source code.

Comment: Yeah, open up another window and use it to run `perldoc`.

Comment: Well, this is too easy ;-), and this is what I was doing until now. I work by ssh connection+gnu-screen and create a new shell for the perldocs, but then you need to search for the method (copy paste or write yourself) and this is a bit distracting. On the other hand the code here  was a proof of concept. For real usage, I will wrap these lines in a method and pass `($module, $method)`.

Comment: Perhaps try KomodoEdit.  I believe it will show you docs when you begin crafting a call to the sub.

Comment: The thing is that I only use only-text environments (shell, vi, emacs -nw and the debuger or pdl2 for interactive perl), so komodo, eclipse, perlpod-web environments are not a desirable option. Having said that I was very fond of Komodo 5 years ago when I needed to use windows in my laptop, but I have been without using any IDE since then. Only coding Perl in `emacs -nw` nowadays (where the c-perl module gives you also POD viewing from your sources).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also could find any single CPAN module that does exactly want you want.

I wonder if you could somehow combine [Pod::Coverage](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pod%3a%3aCoverage) and [Pod::Select](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Pod%3a%3aSelect).

Pod::Coverage lets you get at the symbols as below:

```
snoopy@deb6:~$ perl -de0
DB<1> use Pod::Coverage
DB<2> our $pc = Pod::Coverage->new(package => 'Mouse');
DB<3> $pc->coverage;
DB<4> use Data::Dumper
DB<5> p Dumper $pc->{symbols}
$VAR1 = {
  'around' => 1,
  'init_meta' => 0,
  'super' => 0,
  'has' => 1,
  'after' => 1,
  'augment' => 0,
  'inner' => 0,
  'override' => 0,
  'with' => 0,
  'extends' => 1,
  'before' => 1
};
```

Maybe Pod::Select (or Similar) could then be used to extract the relevant sections?

**EDIT** or maybe subclass/modify Pod::Coverage to gather body text along with the symbols.

Comment: I have look at the source code and package Pod::Coverage::Extractor (coded inside Pod::Coverage file) has the method Command that I can use to extract the data. I am creating an answer to document it but I will accept your answer to give you the recognition of pointing me in a good direction

Comment: @Pablo (A very late afterthought) I recently came across Devel::Command which does a nice job of extending the Perl debugger REPL, letting you add new commands.

Answer (score 1):

[PDL](http://pdl.perl.org/)'s interactive shell ([perldl](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=perldl&title=perldl)) lets you [read PDL's docs](http://pdl.perl.org/?docs=perldl&title=perldl#shortcuts_and_aliases) with the `?` and `??` commands, perhaps something like that can be done for REPL.

Comment: Thanks Joel, I am looking something similar, so the reason of asking for a module is to see what people have 'invented' for structuring/flagging the POD in a way that you can extract later specific info. I like the R approach to documentation (and talking about good things in R documentation: sweave)